# Creating a system that shows your checkbox selection AFTER the form submit

Tags: jquery, html, forms, checkbox, form-submit

I created several checkbox options which can be chosen and submitted. Depending on the selection a certain SQL statement is performed.

Though, i want to make some fancy box that shows the (checkbox) selection after the form is submitted. I think javascript is the way to to it, though i am open for all solutions (php, jquery, etc.)

I already created something but this shows the selection at the moment it is being selection, and when the form is submitted the made selection showing box will be gone.

What i have now:
**The HTML**

```
<form method="post">
    <div id="list4" class="dropdown-check-list">
        <span class="anchor">Select stage of Living Lab</span>
        <ul class="items">
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="columns_stage[]" value="Starting phase" id="Starting-Phase" onclick="displaySelectedCheckBox(this)" />Starting phase</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="columns_stage[]" value="Running phase" id="Running-Phase" onclick="displaySelectedCheckBox(this)" />Running phase</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" name="columns_stage[]" value="Completed" id="Completed" onclick="displaySelectedCheckBox(this)" />Completed</li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" class="select-all" id="select-all" value="Select/deselect all"/>Select/deselect all</li>
        </ul>
    </div>  

<input type="submit" name="go" value="Submit" onclick="displaySelectedCheckBox(this)"/>
</form>
```

**The javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

function displaySelectedCheckBox(id) {
    if (id.checked) {
        if (document.getElementById(id.value + "-disp")) {
            document.getElementById(id.value + "-disp").innerHTML = id.value;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("displayHere").innerHTML = document.getElementById("displayHere").innerHTML + '<p id="' + id.value + '-disp" >' + id.value + '</p>';
        }
    } else {
        document.getElementById(id.value + "-disp").innerHTML = "";
    }
}

</script>
```

**Other bit of HTML that shows the selection (relatively standard now for testing):**

```
<div id="displayHere">

</div>
```

So the question is, how can i make the code to work so that it shows the selection AFTER the form is submitted instead right at the time it is being selected (both would be even better, selection visible when it is being selected AND after the submitting of the form).

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inline php is the answer (since your form method is "post and your form action is blank, it will  post to itself...so the data is available if the form has been submitted). When you post the form, just check if those post variables are set, if they are then display them with an echo...

```
<div id="displayHere"><?php if(isset($_POST['columns_stage1'])){echo $_POST['columns_stage1'] . ' was selected';} ?></div>
```

just remember that post variables are named after the  "name" attribute, so make sure they are named different...otherwise the last one set will prevail.